# How Can I Edit Python's Tuple?

Tags: python

**How Can I Replace An Element In Tuple In Python ?**

```
# An EX 

myTuple = ("Ahmed", "Hossam", "Ibrahim")

# Now I Want To Replace "Ahmed" With another Element, How ?
```

I Tried The Methods Of Lists And String But Its Didn't Work, I Know That Tuples Are Immutable But It Has To Be A Way To Edit It , Right ?

Comment: I don't think you understand what "immutable" means...

Comment: There is no way to edit.  You must create a new tuple.

Comment: `myTuple = ("another Element", "Hossam", "Ibrahim")`.  Note that this doesn't modify the original tuple, but if the only reference to it is `myTuple`, that doesn't matter.

Comment: The **reason for using** a tuple is **specifically to prevent** such a change. That's **what "immutable" means**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myTuple = ("Ahmed", "Hossam", "Ibrahim")

myList = list(myTuple)

index_to_replace = myList.index("Ahmed")

myList[index_to_replace] = "NewElement"

myTuple = tuple(myList)